# SPARQL - get properties by label

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

For my current project I need to extract information from dbpedia. The only information I have is the label of the resource.

To give you an example:

I have the resource "car". Now I would like to get e.g. the abstract.
Is there a way to solve this with SPARQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That other answer doesn't get you results from DBpedia, which is what you said you wanted.  It's also not clear whether you want results for resources which label *includes* your known string, or *is* your known string.

A couple of examples, directly linked to query forms and results, presuming you only care about English abstracts and labels...

#### [Label case-insensitively includes `car`](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20bif%3A%20%20%3Cbif%3A%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FitemLabel%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FitemDescription%20%0D%0A%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%22car%22%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3FitemDescription%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemDescription%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemLabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FitemLabel&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) ([live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20bif%3A%20%20%3Cbif%3A%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3FitemLabel%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FitemDescription%20%0D%0A%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%20%20bif%3Acontains%20%20%22car%22%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3FitemDescription%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemDescription%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemLabel%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3FitemLabel&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on))

```
PREFIX  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX   dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX   bif:  <bif:>

SELECT DISTINCT ?itemLabel  
                ?item  
                ?itemDescription 
 WHERE
   {  
     ?item       rdfs:label    ?itemLabel .
     ?itemLabel  bif:contains  "car" .
     ?item       dbo:abstract  ?itemDescription .
     FILTER (lang(?itemDescription) = 'en')
     FILTER (lang(?itemLabel) = 'en')
   }
ORDER BY ?itemLabel
```

#### [Label is exactly `"Car"@en`](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%0D%0A%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3FitemLabel%20%20%3D%20%20%22Car%22%40en%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3FitemDescription%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemDescription%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FitemLabel&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) ([live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20%20rdfs%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F01%2Frdf-schema%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20%20%20dbo%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20*%0D%0A%20WHERE%0D%0A%20%20%20%7B%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%20%20%20%3FitemLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20%3FitemLabel%20%20%3D%20%20%22Car%22%40en%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3Aabstract%20%20%3FitemDescription%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FitemDescription%29%20%3D%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20ORDER%20BY%20%3FitemLabel&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on))

```
PREFIX  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX   dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT *
 WHERE
   {  
     ?item       rdfs:label    ?itemLabel .
     FILTER ( ?itemLabel  =  "Car"@en ) .
     ?item       dbo:abstract  ?itemDescription .
     FILTER (lang(?itemDescription) = 'en')
   }
 ORDER BY ?itemLabel
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking by label, for example:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription WHERE{  
  ?item ?label "Car"@en.    
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>. 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
```

you get several items:

[image]

You can see it on [Wikidata Query Page](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20distinct%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20WHERE%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22Car%22%40en.%20%20%0A%20%20%23%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AinLanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2F%3E.%09%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D). (I prefer Wikidata Query services to DBpedia).

So you need to specify some additional parameter to get only required item.

Comment: works fine. Thanks a lot. Didn´t know about Wikidata

Comment: Where did you get that idea? DBpedia ingests Wikidata; Wikidata does not ingest DBpedia. See [various people comparing the projects](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Wikidata-and-DBpedia), [Wikidata talking about DBpedia](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Wikidata/Notes/DBpedia_and_Wikidata), [DBpedia talking about Wikidata](http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/)...

Comment: as i understand Wikipedia is based on Wikidata, but DBpedia just dump of Wikipedia data. So, if you want to be in sync with Wikipedia, it's better to use Wikidata. For my project I need data from Wiki, so I selected Wikidata.

Comment: @TallTed, and these links, which you gave, they are old and outdated. I think future for Wikidata.

Comment: Your understanding is flawed, at best. Wikipedia started long before, and therefore cannot be based on, Wikidata. The pages I linked do need some updating, but they remain generally accurate. [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) has generally lagged 6 months or more behind Wikipedia updates, but [DBpedia-Live](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql) generally reflects firehose updates within hours if not minutes.

Comment: other reasons why I prefer Wikidata, it's easy to use and it has nice tutorial, which DBpedia doesn't have.

Comment: So you don't care about the data, so much as the tutorial and (for you) ease-of-use...  You might try other interfaces to DBpedia -- [Interactive SPARQL (GUI query builder)](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/isparql/) and [Facet Browser](http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/fct/).

Comment: Thank you, I'll look. I care about data, as I understand Wikidata has the same data as Wikipedia. I just needed fast solution, I looked at these 3 ways: Freebase, DBpedia and Wikidata. Freebase is closed. I'm going to use DBpedia as fallback anyway. And I need to compare their performances too.

Comment: you can look at my search page using Wikidata: http://corerat1.azurewebsites.net/Home/Wiki

Comment: Another more recent [discussion of the two projects, and their mutually beneficial relationship](https://medium.com/virtuoso-blog/on-the-mutually-beneficial-nature-of-dbpedia-and-wikidata-5fb2b9f22ada)

Comment: @TallTed, so you can combine wikidata and dbpedia using one query?

Comment: Yes, you can combine Wikidata and DBpedia using one query. Neither of their public endpoints permits `SERVICE` queries against remote endpoints, so you have to do something elsewhere. For instance, you can set up your own DBpedia mirror, and include a `SERVICE`-based subquery against Wikidata; or (as in the article I cited) you can use a third endpoint which permits remote `SERVICE` queries, to blend those two remote queries.