# SPARQL DBpedia get properties of a person knowing their name

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

new to SPARQL. Trying to figure out why I get different results on these two queries. It's based on [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366786), where I'm trying to match properties to a name of a person. For example, I'm curious to know the birthday of J.K. Rowling, without knowing her URI directly. Here's the code from the link above:

```
PREFIX  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX   dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT *
 WHERE
   {  
     ?item       rdfs:label    ?itemLabel .
     FILTER ( ?itemLabel  =  "Car"@en ) .
     ?item       dbo:abstract  ?itemDescription .
     FILTER (lang(?itemDescription) = 'en')
   }
 ORDER BY ?itemLabel
```

compared to the query I'd like with J.K.:

```
PREFIX  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX   dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT *
 WHERE
   {  
     ?item       rdfs:label    ?itemLabel .
     FILTER ( ?itemLabel  =  "J.K. Rowling"@en ) .
     ?item       dbo:abstract  ?itemDescription .
     FILTER (lang(?itemDescription) = 'en')
   }
 ORDER BY ?itemLabel
```

The first one works fine, however, when I replace "Car" with "J.K. Rowling" as in the second, nothing is returned (her URI is return if I remove the dbo:abstract line and the filter line for it). J.K. Rowling does have a dbo:abstract in English. I'm not sure why it works for one and not the other. The only thing I can see that that 'Car' is a 'Thing', while J.K. is a 'person'

Comment: There's a typo in the itemLabel value in your query: It should be `"J. K. Rowling"@en`. Notice the space between `J.` and `K.`.

Comment: right, and `J.K. Rowling` without the space works when omitting the `dbo:abstract` because this is one of the many redirecting pages to the "main" resource in DBpedia (resp. Wikipedia). Open `http://dbpedia.org/resource/J.K._Rowling` in the browser and you'll be forwarded to `http://dbpedia.org/resource/J._K._Rowling`

Comment: Check `PREFIX  rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX   dbo:  <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT DISTINCT *
 WHERE
   {  
     ?item       rdfs:label    ?itemLabel .
     FILTER ( ?itemLabel  =  "J. K. Rowling"@en ) .
?redirectingItem dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?item
     
   }
 ORDER BY ?itemLabel ?redirectingItem` how many (partially weird) resources are redirected.

Comment: ahhh, so in the future I'll be mindful of how the spaces line up with `_` characters in the URI. I wrote a query based on @UninformedUser's response that returns the uri or optionally the redirect uri if it exists. If one of you wants to write your suggestions as an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll put in my solution

Comment: @errorline1 feel free to answer your own question and don't forget to click on "accept" then